# chrome extensions: how do I make a tab navigate backwards in history

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, back

I am using chrome and am making an extension. I would like to know if it is possible to make a tab navigate backwards (like pushing the back button). if so, how do I do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this [`history`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.history) object.

```
window.history.go(-1);
```

Comment: it's not working, can you not use this on error pages? like the "not connected to internet" page.

Comment: I believe the error pages like that are special and can not have script injected into them.

Comment: dang, thats too bad. I just did some tests, and it won't let me inject anything.